# One redundant equation in linear program?

Tags: optimization, proof-explanation, linear-programming, operations-research, optimal-transport

Consider the general linear programming formulation of the transportation problem (see Table 8.6). Verify that the set of $(m+n)$ functional constraint equations $(m$ supply constraints and $n$ demand constraints) has one redundant equation, i.e. any one equation can be reproduced from a linear combination of the other $(m+n-1)$ equations.

The table 8.6 is

[image]

and the solution is

[image]

though I don't understand it.

Why each constraint column will have exactly two nonzero entries?

If we multiply by $-1$ the demand constraints then I can see where the $-1$ comes from but not the $+1.$

I don't see the conclusion *since the total supply equals the total demand. Hence, there is a redundant constraint* neither .

Could someone please help me to understand?

thank you.

Comment: There is a linear dependency between the rows: adding (+1) times the constraint rows and (-1) times the demand rows is zero.

Comment: I don't understand @MichalAdamaszek

Comment: Suppose $x=(1,1,,\ldots,1,-1,-1,\ldots,-1)$ where there is 1 for all supply constraints and -1 for all demand constraints. Then $x^TA=0$. So your constraints are linearly dependent. So (at least) one of them can be removed.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek What is $A$? Is the matrix in my post? If so, why to do $x^TA=0$?

Comment: @Alt. could you accept the answer?

Comment: @LinAlg but I haven't understand the second part yet.

Comment: @Alt. let me give an easier example: if $x\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and if the constraints are $x_1=1$, $x_2=2$ and $2x_1 + x_2 = 4$, you can leave out one of those three constraints, and the constraint you leave out will still be satisfied since the constraints are linearly dependent.

Answer (score 1):

> Why each constraint column will have exactly two nonzero entries?

In the following picture I have multiplied all demand constraints with $-1$, and highlighted one column. Indeed there is one +1 and one -1.
[image]

> I don't see the conclusion since the total supply equals the total demand. Hence, there is a redundant constraint neither .

This is another way to say it: if you add all constraint rows except for the very last one (in the picture in this post), almost all +1/-1 cancel out and you end up with the last demand constraint (times negative 1).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understood the first part but not the second one.

Comment: Why to add all constraint rows except for the very last one ?

Comment: How would they cancel out? They would cancel out if you add them in a 'vertical' way +1-1 ?

Comment: @Alt. the last one was chosen randomly: you can leave out any row and sum the other rows. They cancel out because for example for $x_{12}$ you get +1x_{12} from the supply constraints and $-1 x_{12}$ from the demand constraints, and adding those gives $0 x_{12}$.

Comment: How or why this sum and cancelation implies that there is a redundant constraint ?

Comment: The last constraint is a linear combination of the first ones. So if $x$ satisfies all-but-one constraint, it automatically satisfies the last one.

Comment: You wrote, `if you add all constraint rows except for the very last one (in the picture in this post), almost all +1/-1 cancel out and you end up with the last demand constraint (times negative 1).` actually won't one end up with last demand constraint (times negative 1) and another supply constraint (times positive 1) ?

Comment: @Alt. if you add rows, the result is only one row. I do not see how you can end up with more than one row.

Comment: I think I am understanding, (for supply constraints) adding rows yields n, for the 2nd row yields n, and so on. (for demand constraints) adding rows yields -n,-n,...,-n. Hence the last row would be -1 ,-1 ,...,-1 ?

Comment: @Alt. you are adding columns (and end up with a vector (-n,-n,...,-n,-1,...,-1)). What I propose is to add the rows (so you add the numbers in the rectangle in my figure except for the number in the very last demand constraint, and do that for each rectangle).

Comment: I am adding rows which are horizontal lines

Comment: @Alt. if you add two rows (two horizontal lines) the numbers you add are above each other. What you do is adding *along* a row, which is different (and does not answer the original question).

Comment: ok. Regarding to your other comment, the rectangle in your figure is the black line along $x_{12}$ column ?

Comment: Reading one of your first comments, the answer for my comment above is _yes_. How do you know this `The last constraint is a linear combination of the first ones. ` ?

Comment: @Alt. that follows directly from the fact that it is the sum of the other constraints (times negative one).

Comment: I don't see that. I can see that it's the same argument that you mentioned in your comment about $x\in\mathbb R^2$

Comment: @Alt. small example with 2 suppliers and 2 customers, the four rows in the coefficient matrix are (after multiplying the demand constraints with -1): $x_{11} + x_{12}$, $x_{21}+x_{22}$, $-x_{11}-x_{21}$, $-x_{12}-x_{22}$. What do you get if you add the first three rows?

Comment: this $x_{21}+x_{22}$

Comment: @Alt. did you mean $x_{12}+x_{22}$? Isn't that exactly the constraint we omitted in our summation (times negative one)?

Comment: no. adding the first three rows yields $x_{21}+x_{22}$. To your second question,well yes.

Comment: really off topic, but I've notice that you and I have the same badges: 1 gold, 5 gray and 21 orange triangles.. haha :D

Comment: @Alt. focusing on the important details, haha :D