# Why basic feasible solution of a transportation problem always involves not more than $m+n-1$ allocations?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

I was reading Balanced transportation problem. I got stuck in the conditions of Basic Feasible solution.

If we suppose a transportation problem where $m$ number of supply points and $n$ number of demand points then why the basic feasible solution always involves  not more than $m+n-1$ allocations.

**My confusion ---**  If we consider this transportation problem as L.P.P problem then it will have  $m+n$ equations and $mn$ variable. So we can get $m+n$ basic variable. i.e there can be $m+n$ allocation .

But it does not happen. Whenever we see there is $m+n$ allocations we can be confident that there is a loop.

Can anyone please help me to understand where I am missunderstanding?

Can anyone please help me ?

Comment: did I answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

The transportation problem only has $m+n-1$ independent constraints, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3018213/one-redundant-equation-in-linear-program). That means that there cannot be $m+n$ basic variables, but only $n+m-1$.

Comment: I think this question it's actually a duplicate of my question. Isn't it?

Comment: @Alt. yes, although you seemed more appreciative of the answer :)